# Automapper map from inner property to destination class

Tags: c#, automapper

Cant' seem to figure this one out.

```
public class DestinationClass
{
    public int InnerPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string StrignValue { get; set; }
}

public class SourceClass
{
    public InnerValue Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerValue
{
    public int InnerPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string StrignValue {get;set;}
}
```

I need to map from SourceClass.InnerValue directly to DestinationClass. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As usual, right after I hit post question button:

```
Mapper.Reset();
// from, to
Mapper.CreateMap<InnerValue, DestinationClass>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .ConvertUsing(s => Mapper.Map<InnerValue, DestinationClass>(s.Inner));

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var source = new SourceClass() { Inner = new InnerValue() { InnerPropertyId = 123, StringValue = "somethinges" } };

var dest = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(source);
```

Answer (score 6):

We did have a problem with the ConvertUsing not giving the fully populated result because our version of SourceClass had an additional value that we wanted to map to the DestinationClass

We did find that the following code gave the desired result:

```
{
    ...
    Mapper.CreateMap<InnerValue, DestinationClass>(MemberList.Source);
    Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(MemberList.Source)
          .ConstructUsing(s => Mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(s.Inner))
          .ForSourceMember(m => m.Inner, opt => opt.Ignore());
    ...
}

public class DestinationClass
{
    public int InnerPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public string SourceClassValue { get; set; }
}

public class SourceClass
{
    public string SourceClassValue { get; set; }
    public InnerValue Inner { get; set; }
}

public class InnerValue
{
    public int InnerPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string StrignValue {get;set;}
}
```

ConstructUsing continues to map the remaining members after it has mapped the inner members and ConvertUsing does not.

Comment: This is really nice, but a problem: configuration validation fails, as destination members constructed from `Mapper.Map<DestinationClass>(s.Inner)` are still reported as unmapped

Comment: I updated the answer to solve your issue.  The "MemberList.Source" is the key and reduces the number of ignores that are necessary.

Comment: In my understanding, it neglect destination members verification, which is not allowed for my case. What I desire is the verification can understand some destination members already mapped by `ConstructUsing` and continue to verify remaining members. I guess it's not possible as `ConstructUsing` resolves at runtime. So my conclusion for now is to do as in your answer plus adding a companion test. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Mapping should looks as follows:

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .ForMember(x => x.InnerPropertyId , x => x.MapFrom(z => z.Inner.InnerPropertyId))
    .ForMember(x => x.StrignValue , x => x.MapFrom(z => z.Inner.StrignValue))
;
```

Comment: Looks good :) However manually configuring each prop is exactly what I was trying to avoid...

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach migth be to make use of the [Flattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) feature.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
    .IncludeMembers(s => s.Inner);
```

Automapper then will use members from `InnerValue` just like there are in the SourceClass itself